# How to implement case insensitive URL matching using gorilla mux

Tags: go, gorilla

I need to implement case insensitive URL matching in gorilla mux as [it is done here for built in mux](https://grokbase.com/p/gg/golang-nuts/1337v1v6r7/go-nuts-http-handlefunc-case-insensitive-path-match-default-match)

I tried to achieve the same using middle-ware like this

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.Use(srv.GetCaseMiddleware())

//GetCaseMiddleware middleware to make match URL case insensitive
func (srv *Server) GetCaseMiddleware() (w mux.MiddlewareFunc) {
    var middleware mux.MiddlewareFunc = func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            r.URL.Path = strings.ToLower(r.URL.Path)
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
    return middleware
}
```

but still it throws 404 if URL case is changed,is there any way to implement it using gorilla-mux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of this writing, middleware functions are invoked **after** URL matching in `gorilla/mux`.

> Mux supports the addition of middlewares to a Router, which are executed in the order they are added if a match is found, including its subrouters.

I would suggest going with the example in the link you provided.

e.g.

```
func CaselessMatcher(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.URL.Path = strings.ToLower(r.URL.Path)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Then, just wrap your multiplexer.

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
//...
handler := CaselessMatcher(r)
```

It's actually not bad IMO.